# Pass connection object to ASP.Net webservice from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice providing AS400 data.
This webservice has a fixed connection string that I wish to make dynamic.See code below:

```
    Public Function GetData(sql As String) As DataTable

            Dim _data As DataTable

            Try

                Dim s As String = "Provider=IBMDA400"

                s &= ";Data Source=" & "x.x.x.x"
                s &= ";User Id=" & "USER"
                s &= ";Password=" & "PASS"
                s &= ";Default Collection=" & "AAABBB"

                con = New OleDbConnection(s)

                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

                With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = sql
                End With

                Dim dap As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

                con.Open()

                Dim dat As New DataSet

                dap.Fill(dat)

                con.Close()
                con.Dispose()

                _data = dat.Tables(0)

            Catch ex As Exception

                _data = New DataTable

            End Try

            Return _data

        End Function
```

A sample webservice function that uses the above:

```
<WebMethod()> _
        Public Function GetPicklistLines(picklist As String) As List(Of PicklistLine)

            Dim lines As New List(Of PicklistLine)
            Dim line As PicklistLine

            sql = "select " & _
                                    "OLPLNO,OLPLLI,OLORNO,OLLINE,OLPRDC,OLDESC,OLOQTS,OLCQTS,OLUNIT,OLORDS,PGDRNR, AAV01, AAV02, NAV03 " & _
                                    "from SRBSOL " & _
                                    "left outer join SRBPRG on PGPRDC=OLPRDC " & _
                                    "left outer join Z2OOCFGF on F0ERNC=OLORNO and F0A2NB=OLLINE " & _
                                    "where OLPLNO=" & picklist & " and OLSTAT <>' D'"

            data = GetData(sql)

            ' TODO: insert ROW 0 to set active:
            sql = "insert " & _
                    "into SRBSOL " & _
                    "(OLPLNO, OLPLLI) " & _
                    "values " & _
                    "(" & picklist & "," & 0 & ") " & _
                    "where OLPLNO=" & picklist & " and OLSTAT <>' D'"

            For Each dr As DataRow In data.Rows

                ' TODO: get reported quantity:
                sql = "select " & _
                        "RCBAQT " & _
                        "from Z2OOREXC " & _
                        "where RCPLNO='" & picklist & "' and RCPLLI='" & dr("OLPLLI") & "'"

                line = New PicklistLine

                With line
                    .PicklistNumber = picklist
                    .OrderNumber = IIf(TypeOf (dr("OLORNO")) Is DBNull, "", dr("OLORNO"))
                    .PicklistLinenumber = IIf(TypeOf (dr("OLPLLI")) Is DBNull, "", dr("OLPLLI"))
                    .Item = IIf(TypeOf (dr("OLPRDC")) Is DBNull, "", dr("OLPRDC"))
                    .ItemDescription = IIf(TypeOf (dr("OLDESC")) Is DBNull, "", dr("OLDESC"))
                    .InnerColor = IIf(TypeOf (dr("AAV01")) Is DBNull, "", dr("AAV01"))
                    .OuterColor = IIf(TypeOf (dr("AAV02")) Is DBNull, "", dr("AAV02"))
                    .Length = IIf(TypeOf (dr("NAV03")) Is DBNull, "", dr("NAV03"))
                    .Unit = IIf(TypeOf (dr("OLUNIT")) Is DBNull, "", dr("OLUNIT"))
                    .Quantity = IIf(TypeOf (dr("OLCQTS")) Is DBNull, "", CInt(dr("OLCQTS")))
                    .Needed = IIf(TypeOf (dr("OLOQTS")) Is DBNull, "", CInt(dr("OLOQTS")))
                End With

                lines.Add(line)

            Next

            Return lines

        End Function
```

The above function gets called by jquery:

```
function GetAllPicklists() {
    $('#page_overview_search').addClass('ui-disabled');
    $("#Picklists").html('');
    //$("#MemberList").addClass("loading");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://" + host + "/services/picklists.asmx/GetAllPicklists",
        data: "{'customer':'" + $('#select-customer').val() + "', 'route':'" + $('#select-route').val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnGetAllPicklistsSuccess,
        error: OnError
    });
}
```

I have modified the webservice function to provide JSON but that's work in progress... :)

Everything is working as expected, but I wish to make the connection string **s**
from *GetData* dynamic. How should I go about setting a (not yet defined) connection object with values for **Data Source** (IP), **User Id**, **Password** and **Default Collection**.
Specifically how to pass that connection object and the service function call parameters in the jquery POST **data** parameter? Is it possible to set this connection object at login in the future?

Please feel free to ask questions to clarify things that are unclear to you.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of ASW are you using?

Comment: Question asked 2013, switched jobs.. :)

Comment: I know, you just don't run into IBS customers in the wild very often.

Answer (score 0):

passing data through a service call is not a good choice. Your sql connnection string can be easily hacked. you can use wcf service and use message contract to pass information.